# Legend same colour as bullet

Tags: highcharts

Working on a project where Highcharts is used to display charts. However, I want the legend to have the same colour as the bullets.

Here is an image as reference:

[image: reference]

I want the '0 - 2 sec' to be purple and the '3 - 5 sec' to be orange.

Comment: Ok, and why this doesn't work for you? This is default behavior, almost all examples works that way (unless you set some options to prevent this). For example [this one](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked). Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? Thanks.

Comment: @Lars do you mean you want the text font color to be the same color as the marker point in the legend?

Comment: @wergeld Yes indeed, if possible. I found out I can do `name: '<span style="color:red">foo</span>`, but it isn't very dynamic this way. Might be a different solution I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the legend labelFormatter function to accomplish this.

```
legend: {
  labelFormatter: function () {
    return '<span style="color:'+this.color+';">'+this.name+'</span>';
  }
}
```

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/mcffqo1x/